# Trying to add zendesk sdk

Tags: android, sdk, dependencies, build.gradle, zendesk

I am trying to add the zendesk sdk to my app and seem to be getting issues

build.gradle(Project:my app)

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'

}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo' }
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/" }
}
}
```

build.gradle (Module: MyModule)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/' }
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
jcenter()

flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}
}

dependencies {
   ...
   implementation 'com.zendesk:sdk:1.11.0.1'
}
```

im trying to change implementation 'com.zendesk:sdk:1.11.0.1' to 'com.zendesk:support:3.0.1' to get to add the zendesk live chat to my app.

I either get cannot resolve com.zendesk:support:3.0.1 or AAPT2 error about it not being able to mergeResources.

Comment: It is probably conflict with some other library. If I remember correctly zopIM had an issues with some Picasso or Glide versions

Comment: @Antonis Radz I dont have either of those i have universal-image-loader